# Rendering view or handlebars template in leaflet popup

Tags: ember.js, leaflet

I have a question for the [`ember-leaflet`](https://github.com/gabesmed/ember-leaflet) library and the right use of popups.

The following example from the [`ember-leaflet` website](http://gabesmed.github.io/ember-leaflet/) uses the library to add markers and linked popups. It also illustrates how to add content for the popups via content binding.

```
RadMarkersApp = Ember.Application.create();
RadMarkersApp.MarkerLayer =
  EmberLeaflet.MarkerLayer.extend(
    EmberLeaflet.DraggableMixin,
    EmberLeaflet.PopupMixin, {
  popupContentBinding: 'content.title'
});

RadMarkersApp.MarkerCollectionLayer =
  EmberLeaflet.MarkerCollectionLayer.extend({
    content: [{
      location: L.latLng(40.7127, -74.0060),
      title: 'City Hall'}],
    itemLayerClass: RadMarkersApp.MarkerLayer
  });

RadMarkersApp.IndexView =
  EmberLeaflet.MapView.extend({
    childLayers: [
      EmberLeaflet.DefaultTileLayer,
      RadMarkersApp.MarkerCollectionLayer]});
```

Now I would like to be able to use a view or Handlebars template for the `popupContent` property here. Does somebody have any ideas how to implement this? Are there any best practices for this scenario?

My first approach:

```
App.MarkerLayer =
  EmberLeaflet.MarkerLayer.extend(
    EmberLeaflet.PopupMixin, {

    popupContent: function() {
      // Render view (how to get?) or handlebars template
      return Ember.TEMPLATES['popup-content'](this.get('content'))
    }.property()
  });
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little idiot not beeing able to look up helpfull functions in the documentation.

I was able to fix this with a little hack and the help of `Ember.View#createElement`:

```
App.MarkerLayer = EmberLeaflet.MarkerLayer.extend(EmberLeaflet.PopupMixin, {
  popupContent: function() {
    view = this.view = this._parentLayer.createChildView('map-popup');
    view.set('context', this.get('content'));
    Ember.View.states.inDOM.enter(view)
    view.createElement();

    return view.get('element');
  }.property()
});
```

Hope this will help others.

Comment: Seems a bit "hacky" to me. It seems a bit like messing with Ember's internal state (I could be wrong, as a newcomer to Ember). In either case, did you ever find a cleaner/better way to do this?

Comment: Just tried this, and getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'createChildView'". Tips?

Comment: Fixed it by replacing your first line in the function with "view = this.view = this._parentLayer.createChildLayer(App.MapPopupView)". Maybe due to Ember versions... I'm getting a deprecation warning that "Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup] see: http://git.io/EKPpnA". No idea what that means yet, but will have to look into it.

Comment: Yes, I know, this fix/hack is not nearly complete. It was there reason I moved away from Ember because it often complicate things in special situations like this. I recommand to take a fresh look into the Ember-Leaflet library again. I think they fixed and added some features to help us with variable content.